# about ADHOC build -getting error when i install it to my device

Tags: iphone, xcodebuild, adhoc-queries

signer is not valid..
i noticed while i am setting up settings for build i didnt see release option in my project info->configaurations, we have to duplicate releases option and place distribution here 
can any one send me solution for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have placed developer profile in place of distribution profile

when i select distribution profile it get solved my problem